# Create user in Deployd with Phonegap app

Tags: cordova, deployd

How can I create a new user in **Deployd** with **Phonegap** app?

A `POST` request on `/users` in the browser works, but in Phonegap app it returns the error:

```
[phonegap] [console.log] Cannot POST /users
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you have to pre-download your dpd.js from

```
http://yourserver.com/dpd.js
```

and change the following in the code:

```
var root = "http://yourserver.com/"
```

And use that in your HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/dpd.js"></script>
```